# Launched command line is missing existing files

Tags: c, windows

The problem that I have is that when I launch a command line instance from within my code, it seems that is missing files that should normally exist.

Here is a photo that clearly shows the issue:

Image Link: https://image.prntscr.com/image/5yylGu-WQoKddilN9mu8Tg.png

As you can see the CMD launched through my program is "missing" around a thousand files, that the other normal CMD instances are not.

What I have tried to solve the issue is to change the architecture at which I am building the executable (I tried both x32 and x64) with no change whatsoever.

Additionally I tried to use different functions to launch the command line, such as `system` and `WinExec` without any success as well.

The code that I use to launch the CMD instance inside my program is the following:

```
STARTUPINFO si = { sizeof(STARTUPINFO) };
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

if (!CreateProcessA("C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\cmd.exe",
                   "",
                   NULL, NULL, 0, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
{
    printf("CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError());
}
```

The code executes successfully without any error, but the result of the `dir` command inside the System32 folder is showing the output that I have captured in the photo above; only 3.011 from the 4.782 files are being shown.

Therefore my question is why this is happening, and what is the pitfall that I have fallen into.

Comment: How is `cmake` tag relates to the problem?

Comment: @Tsyvarev I just thought I should also indicate that I am using ```cmake``` to compile my program. Usually I wouldn't put this tag on my question, but due to the fact that the issue I have is quite weird I added it as well since I do not know what is causing the trouble. Should I remove it ?

Comment: If you think that way how your program is **built** is important, than describe that way in the question post. Otherwise the tag related to the building process has no sense. BTW, your image isn't shown properly: Stack Overflow requires images to be available with `https` protocol, but your image can be read only with `http` one.

Comment: Also, standard-specific tags (like `c99` in your question) should be added only if you think that problem could be related to the standard used. Otherwise, use version-generic language tag. And correctly choose between C and C++: The code you show is for C language, but you use `C++` tag.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I have changed the tags at this post according to your observations and comments. Thank you! Regarding the photo the link itself is in imgur which uses https protocol by default (which is also included in my url). I don't know why this is happening.

Comment: UPDATE: I have added the photo's url raw into the post in case you want it to see on a better quality.

Answer (score 1):

dir doesn't show ALL files by default, it doesn't show hidden and system files as well as datastreams. That behavior is affected by environment variable DIRCMD. Usually to see all files, one should use something like:

```
 dir /a
```

Comment: I am aware of this flag, but unfortunately this does not seem to solve my problem either. I still get only 3.011 files. What is important to notice is that the files that I cannot list from my program, I cannot execute them either! For example one of the files that my program's CMD is missing is WUDFHost.exe. If I try to execute the file through my program's CMD, I got an error that the file does not exist, even though it is infact there.